# chat() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

My url pattern is

```
url(r'^my/<int:id>/', views.chat, name='chat'),
```

and my view function is like this

```
def chat(request, id):
    snippet = Posted_proj.objects.get(id=id)
    return render(request, 'chat.html')
```

And getting this error  `chat() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'`

I am unable to figure what I am doing wrong . kindly help

Comment: You mix `url(..)` syntax with `path(..)` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Django `url(..)` paths are specified with a *regex*, not with *patch converters*. So your `url(..)` should look like:

```
url(r'^my/(?P<id>\d+)/', views.chat, name='chat'),
```

In [django-2.0](/questions/tagged/django-2.0) and higher, you can use [**`path(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urls/#path) to specify your path:

```
# since Django-2.0
path(r'^my/<int:id>/', views.chat, name='chat'),
```

I would however advise to rename `id` to `posted_id`, or `_id` since [**`id`** [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#id) is a builtin function, and now your function is "hiding" the builtin one. If you later want to use the builtin function, you will use the URL id instead, this can thus result in a lot of confusion.